# How to get information about a button click on 1st activity and use it in the 3rd activity? - android

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-activity

well there are 3 activities say **Act1**, **Act2** and **Act3**.

in **Act1** there are three buttons say **But1**, **But2** and **But3**.

if we click any of the 3 three buttons it will end up showing **Act2**.

in **Act2** there is only one button say **Done**.

my problem is when i click on the button **Done** in **Act2** i should get the information about the button which is clicked in **Act1** to show **Act2** in a **TextView** in **Act3**.

i think i have made it clear..

i just need to know how to pass the information of the *button click* in **Act1** to **Act3**

should i use bundles or something else? pls help me out with the logic and if possible a sample code? :)

Comment: [Take a look at here](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+passing+data+to+activity+which+is+in+dialog+and+get+result+from+it&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#hl=en&biw=1440&bih=785&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+passing+data+to+activity&oq=android+passing+data+to+activity+&aq=0K&aqi=g-K2g-bK2&aql=&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i30l2j0i8i30l2.3.3.1.5168.1.1.0.0.0.0.204.204.2-1.1.0...0.0.v1AAtLw2tVk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1a1f4768cce211b1)

Comment: I think passing int in intent is the simplest option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store which button was pressed.

```
   SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
                Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                prefsEditor.putString("buttonPressed", "Button1");
                prefsEditor.commit();

                }
            });

    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                prefsEditor.putString("buttonPressed", "Button2");
                prefsEditor.commit();

                }
            });

    Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                prefsEditor.putString("buttonPressed", "Button3");
                prefsEditor.commit();

                }
            });
```

And in the `Activity` in which you want to fetch which button was pressed:

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
String whichButton = appSharedPrefs.getString("buttonPressed", "");
if(whichButton.equals("Button1")
 //do something
if(whichButton.equals("Button2")
 //do something
if(whichButton.equals("Button3")
 //do something
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options.

1) The Hardcore option would be to create a database and save / query the information.

2) You could also write to sharedPreferences.
[SharedPrefExample](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

3) As was mentioned in the comment, if your only talking from one activity to another you can just intent.putExtra("key", value)

4) Lastly you can extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
Here is a good post that deals with global variables. [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Comment: thanks a lot :)
which one is better? using database or SharedPref ??

Comment: Having had to do something like this recently I found option 3 was the simplest to implement. Just remember to add the values to the intent launching both Act2 and Act3

Comment: Well. Depends on what type of information you are storing. A sharedPref is def was easier. And you should use that if it's just setting information that isn't going to change a lot. But if it's a lot of info that always changing (in your case I don't think so) then a DB is better.

Answer (score 2):

Try to Use Intent

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("BtnAID", ID);
                Intent It = new Intent();
                It.setClass(A.this, B.class);
                It.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(It);
               }
```